# When creating a BigQuery table I'm getting an error message about hive partitioning

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm creating a table from a CSV text file on my machine. I'm getting this message - Hive partitioned loads require that the HivePartitioningOptions be set, with both a sourceUriPrefix and mode provided. No sourceUriPrefix was provided.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal, complete, and reproducible, sample of your code where you are seeing the problem. For additional reference, see this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.